# ¿como obtener una imagen ubicado en otro servidor?

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando mostrar una imagen en una página alojada en windows server 2016, pero la imagen está guardada en otro servidor y ambos servidores estan conectados en la misma red. Esto lo hago usando php, html y javascript en pruebas los hacía con xampp y cambiando los puertos me mostraba bien la imagen, pero ahora no se como hacer para que se muestren ya que la página se ubica en servidor.

El php que me obtiene las imagenes del servidor es el siguiente...

```
       $ruta_img = "\\\\ipservidor\\imagenes\\imagenes_hoy\\imagen1.png";
       $imagen = base64_encode(file_get_contents($ruta_img));
```

y esto se lo paso a una función javascript que se encarga de mostrarlo en la seccion que requiero.

```
   function mostrarImagenes(imagen1, imagen2) {
      document.getElementById('imgOne').setAttribute('src', 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+imagen1);
      document.getElementById('imgTwo').setAttribute('src', 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+imagen2);      
   }
```

No uso ningun framework es php comun y corriente.

Comment: Prueba a usas las  barras normales para una URL: "/" y http p https al comienzo de la URL de la imagen.

Comment: si dicho servidor tiene un dominio, úsalo sin más y te hará la vida más fácil. Si no, yo me plantearía su creación...

Comment: @Orici ya he probado lo de las barra invertidas y no funciona.

Comment: @AXL no tiene dominio y no se como crear uno.

Comment: ¿Podrías probar a alojar las imágenes en un hosting de imágenes online?  te quitarías problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Una cosa es que el servidor donde está el PHP vea ese directorio compartido en red y OTRA MUY DIFERENTE, que el usuario en su navegador pueda ver ese directorio. Que además, suena a algo muy inseguro.

Si revisas al ver tu página HTML que resulta de procesar el script PHP, verás que se carga un recurso en la img. Esa etiqueta `img` hace que el navegador del usuario haga una petición HTTP buscando otro recurso en una URL. Si el navegador no tiene acceso a la ruta en esa URL, no va a cargar.

Entonces, tienes opciones:

- le das permisos a todos los usuarios a la unidad de red (suena horrible), o
- dispones esos recursos estáticos en una ubicación a la que sí puedan acceder los usuarios desde sus navegadores, o
- implementas una lógica que vaya y busque esos recursos en la unidad de red, los copie en una carpeta temporal del servidor donde se interpreta el PHP y use esa ruta temporal al mostrarlo. Lo que es más lento, costoso y aburrido.

Answer (score -1):

Que los equipos estén en la misma red aporta mayor información, ya que el servidor 2 podría tener un firewall configurado para filtrar (e ignorar) cualquier petición que reciba.

Una pregunta es ¿servidor2 es un servidor web?, porque si es así, no debería existir mayor problema, y el argumento de `file_gets_content` debería ser `http://ip_servidor/.../nom_arch.png`.

Ahora bien, si servidor2 no es un servidor web, una pregunta relacionada, cuya respuesta te podría servir es ¿cómo harías (mediante la consola de window) para copiar en un directorio del servidor1 el archivo disponible en servidor2? La ruta que utilices para lograr esto es la misma que deberías utilizar para tu php.